# Is there is way to configure load balancing mode within manifest yaml when creating GKE ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently HTTP(S) L7 load balancer, created  out of the box by GKE ingress, configures load balancing mode to RPS.I want to set the  load balancing mode to Utilization. Is there a way to configure it within the manifest yaml file? (I don't wan't to set it manually)

Comment: Can you share how is configured your cluster? Especially if you use the Container-native load balancing mode.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for [GKE Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) or [GCP External HTTP(S) Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) ? You dont want to do it manually via UI nor `gcloud command` ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! First things first, a little housekeeping: you will get much better responses here if you post the code you're working with (redacted, naturally) and also list out the things you've already tried. You can edit your post to add more details, rather than creating a new post.

Now, without seeing your manifest file - I'm going to guess that you're talking about an L7 ILB - I would recommend that you use the [API section of the GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#api_4) for reference as you edit your manifest. Translating the JSON reference there into YAML, it would probably look something like this:

```
name: l7-ilb-backend-service
backends:
- group: projects/[project-id]/zones/us-west1-a/instanceGroups/l7-ilb-backend-example
  balancingMode: UTILIZATION
```

Untested, because there's no manifest to work with.